# Easy to use web-based reporting tool

Tags: reporting

I'm looking for recommendations for an easy to use reporting/business intelligence tool that can interface with an sql server or access database. It can be web-based or a desktop tool.

Ideally it would be freeware or low cost, and easy to use for users who are not that technically savvy (below the level of someone who can generate reports and complicated queries in Access).

Any tools I've seen so far (such as Crystal Reports) are either too expensive or too complicated to use for non-power users.

Comment: What type of reports are you interested in generating? Things like sales reports, or things like server performance reports?

Comment: Just things like sales reports. Nothing IT-related e.g. monthly sales, average sales etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Pentaho: http://www.pentaho.com/

Comment: Pentaho would be out of my price range

Comment: You can use the community edition

Answer (score 1):

I've used OpenReports in a low-budget setting: http://oreports.com/

I don't think any of the low-cost solutions are likely to be user-friendly for non-technical users. Smart non-technical people can learn OpenReports, but they can learn to build Access queries too.